# Recipe organiser software for the Mac

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

Could someone recommend me recipe organiser software for the Mac?

I've already looked at [MacGourmet](http://www.macgourmet.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SousChef](http://acaciatreesoftware.com/). Here's a description from [TUAW](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/10/07/first-look-souschef-stores-your-recipies-allows-mac-to-cook/):

> The thing I like most about SousChef
>   is the ability to use your Mac to view
>   recipes while cooking, without ever
>   having to waste paper printing each
>   individual recipe. This is
>   accomplished through a Front Row-esque
>   interface that lists your ingredients,
>   and the cooking instructions -- It
>   will even read your instructions to
>   you while you are cooking. You can
>   control the speech through a heads-up
>   display that appears when you mouse
>   over the bottom portion of your
>   screen. You can also control this
>   "10-foot mode" with your Apple or
>   Keyspan remote.

If SousChef isn't for you, there's a [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5351197/an-exhaustive-geek-guide-to-managing-your-recipes-onlineuide-to-managing-your-recipes-online) about managing recipes online.

Comment: This was part of the MacHeist bundle this year and a awesome package. Or so my wife says anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There was recently a reference of [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) for recipes at [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5289792/five-best-recipe-managers).
The next posting at Lifehacker [referred this article](http://www.deliciouscoma.com/archives/2009/09/saving_recipes_online.html) showing Evernote in use.

Comment: I was going to post this, but you were faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not live in the Mac world but I would strongly recommend what I use, Google Docs. It has all the features I need from a recipe organizer

Comment: how exactly do you use Google Docs to store them? any chance of a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

This question reminded me of Cookbook from the [My Dream App](http://mydreamapp.com/) contest. It's a shame that it seems to have been abandoned.

I've also found [YummySoup!](http://hungryseacow.com/).